# Getting a Captcha error while requesting data from the website

Tags: python, api, beautifulsoup, captcha

I'm working on a Project to detect a license plate and display the owner's information. I'm currently facing an Captcha issue while requesting for vehicle and owner details from a website.

Here's the Python code:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

home_url = 'https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102'
post_url = 'https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/vahan/rcDlHome.xhtml'

first = sys.argv[1]

second = sys.argv[2]

r = requests.get(url=home_url)
cookies = r.cookies
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
viewstate = soup.select('input[name="javax.faces.ViewState"]')[0]['value']

data = {
'javax.faces.partial.ajax':'true',
'javax.faces.source': 'form_rcdl:j_idt59',
'javax.faces.partial.execute':'@ALL',
'javax.faces.partial.render': 'form_rcdl:pnl_show form_rcdl:pg_show form_rcdl:rcdl_pnl',
'form_rcdl:j_idt59':'form_rcdl:j_idt59',
'form_rcdl':'form_rcdl',
'form_rcdl:tf_reg_no1': first,
'form_rcdl:tf_reg_no2': second,
'javax.faces.ViewState': viewstate,
}

r = requests.post(url=post_url, data=data, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
table = SoupStrainer('tr')
soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.get_text(), 'html.parser', parse_only=table)
print(soup.get_text())
```

After running the command "python app1.py MH04GM 9660", I'm getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\apbak\Desktop\API> python app1.py MH04GM 9660

PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_form_rcdl_j_idt32_CaptchaID",{id:"form_rcdl:j_idt32:CaptchaID"});
```

The website from which I'm trying to get owner info is: https://parivahan.gov.in/rcdlstatus/?pur_cd=102

How can I resolve this error? Any help would be great.

Thanking you in advance.